# Как сделать, чтобы (x==1 && x==2 && x==3 && x==4) возвращало true?

Tags: c++, соревнование

Сегодня задали весёлый вопрос по C++ - как добиться, чтобы

```
(x==1 && x==2 && x==3 && x==4)
```

имело значение `true`?

Comment: Тут подразумевается что x - идентификатор или просто любое выражение? Препроцессор разрешен?

Comment: Нечто, обозначаемое одной буквой. Это только идентификатор или не только? я не уверен точно.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48270127/276994

Comment: @VladD, только там же язык не тот?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Это да, но вопрос _похож_.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Навскидку - сразу два варианта: переопределить оператор `==` или оператор приведения. Оператор `&&` сам по себе - вряд ли, только вкупе с каким-то из перечисленных...

Вот, примерно так - https://ideone.com/XM7O1s:

```
struct Cast
{
    int i;
    operator int() { return i++; }
    Cast(int i):i(i){}
};

struct Equl
{
    bool operator==(int) const { return true; }
};
```

Можно, конечно, извратиться - типа сравнение с конкретно 1,2,3 и 4 дает `true`, но это уже сути дела не меняет...

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Спасибо за поправку, но это была оговорка по Фрейду - кончено извращаться :)

Comment: Ну и define всегда при делах)))

Comment: @Qwertiy Неспортивненько как-то :) А вообще приходится задуматься: я в принципе не подумал о `#define` как способе решения. Таки воспитался в духе C++, надо же...

Answer (score 21):

Примерно так

```
class X {
    public:
    bool operator==(int other) {
        return true;
   }
}

x = X();
```

Comment: Полгода программирую на C++, но чтоб он такое умел..

Comment: Прикольное решение!   +1

Comment: @L'Esperanza: Всего полгода? :-P C++ так же неисчерпаем, как атом

Answer (score 18):

В рамках возможностей, предоставляемых С++, вопрос в таких условиях тривиален и неинтересен.

Что уж там мелочиться

```
template <typename L, typename R>
bool operator ==(const L &, const R &)
{
  return true;
}
```

Всем, всегда и везде сплошное `true`... (Не всем, не всегда и не везде, конечно, но идея понятна.)

А далее хоть

```
struct {} x;
```

хоть

```
enum { x };
```

---

Вариант даже для С может выглядеть как

```
static int i;
#define x (++i)
```

Comment: Ну или то же самое с `&&`

Comment: @VladD: Для того, чтобы сделать то же самое с `&&` надо сначала сделать результат `==` пользовательским типом. А это будет более горомоздко.

Comment: Хм, ваша правда.

Answer (score 15):

Еще вариант с перегрузкой operator== для типа, который не может сравниваться с int:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
bool operator==(T&&, int)
{
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::string x;
    std::cout << (x==1 && x==2 && x==3 && x==4) ;
}
```

Comment: Жаль, что нельзя два ответа сразу принять... У Harry два варианта, ваш элегантный...

Comment: @Mikhailo это не важно. :)

Answer (score 13):

Сегодня задал эту задачу своему другу, он, методом научного тыка, нашёл ещё одно странное решение:

```
#include <cstdio> 
#define x 1,2,3,4

int main()
{
    if (x == 1 && x == 2 && x == 3 && x == 4)
        puts("cheater!");
}
```

Comment: Забавно. Можно еще короче: `0,4`.

Comment: В самом деле, необычно. Основное тут -- операция `,` и конечно, приоритеты операций.  Ее результатом будет результат последнего из выполненных через `,` выражений. В конце концов `if (x == 1 && x == 2 && x == 3 && x == 4)` будет эквивалентен `if (4 && 4 == 4)` т.е. реально сравнивается последний из элементов, перечисленных в `x`.

Comment: @avp, откуда `4 &&`, если посто всё левее запятой игнорится и остаётся `4 == 4`?

Comment: @Qwertiy, согласен, вы правы

Answer (score 12):

Вот такой вариант работает:

```
int x = 0;
#include <iostream>
#define x (++x)
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<(x==1&&x==2&&x==3&&x==4)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Препроцессор:

```
#define x true || 0
```

[Пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e02162747ec0054a)

Comment: `#define x true || false` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#define x  1 | 0
#define x  1 | 1
#define x  1 ^ 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
auto a = [mb{ 0 }]()mutable{ return ++mb; };
 
#define x a()

int main()
{
    if (x == 1 && x == 2 && x == 3 && x == 4)
        cout << "wow!" << endl;
}
```

Можно сделать лямбду, которая каждый раз возвращает число на 1 больше, дальше через дефайн имитируем вызов этой лямбды.